# Ресурсы для планшета 16:9

Tags: android, ресурсы, tablet

Есть китайский планшет планшет MAPAN MX913 DC, в какую папку нужно кидать для него ресурсы ? пишу ресурсы в папки
`values-large 
values-sw600dp 
values-sw600dp-land 
values-sw600dp-w720dp 
values-sw720dp 
values-sw720dp-land 
values-xlarge`

но все равно тянет из value

Answer (score 1):

Также добавлю, что квалификаторы sw, w доступны на Android 3.2 и выше, поэтому нужно обязательно добавлять и large, xlarge для более-ранних ОС. Кстати также это означает, что в вопросе нужно указывать версию ОС.

Хотя, например, из недавней практики Kindle Fire Hd почему-то все же берет из values-large, имея на борту Андроид 4.0. То ли тестер приложения ошибся указывая параметры железки, то ли что-то странное в самой прошивки от Амазона. В любом случае учитывайте оба эти варианта задания квалификаторов, но предпочтения отдавайте sw.

Answer (score 0):

Если прочитать [документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), то можно заметить, что 9" это не large, а xlarge.

Comment: xlarge я тоже использую, в вопросе это предпоследняя строчка

Comment: вы написали "пишу ресурсы в папки values-large", а нужно рассчитывать, что он будет брать из xlarge.    
имея root права, можно в build.prop прописать хоть что это 80" телик. 
Что бы узнать диагональ экрана, которая прописана, используйте такой код:

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("debug","Screen inches : " + screenInches);

Comment: я думал, что система берёт ресурсы из папки, которая ближе всего удовлетворяет реальным условиям. действительно странно почему андроид не хочет брать ресурс из той папки, которая ближе всего к реалиям?

Comment: @argamidon, "реалии" прописываются в файле настроек на устройстве. Устройство физически не знает, какого оно размера.